# How can I integrate to Rocket universe u2 database from Mulesoft

Tags: database, integration, mulesoft, universe, rocket

I have some jar files. But so far i am not able to establish test connection using mule out of the box db connector.

My customer already have established connection using uniObjects for java....

Any lead will be helpful.

Comment: What have you tried? what were the errors or results? Please edit your question adding code and configurations. Avoid using screenshots for text information.